# Should php artisan queue:work output all processed jobs?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue, laravel-artisan

I'm using redis queue driver in Laravel 6.14. Today I've realized, that when I'm using `php artisan queue:work` it outputs processed jobs totally randomly. Does anybody come up with the same problem? I thought it outputs all jobs (correctly processed and failed). Thans for any ideas and help.

Comment: do you have a supervisor working on the background ? or another tab you are also running same command ?

Comment: Omg, I suppose it was the reason. Don't know how it happened! Thanks for the help, I'm feeling so stupid now :D